# Absoluteness of Relations for Transitive Models

Tags: logic, set-theory

I am wondering if it's true in general that:

> $ ( A \text{ is an antichain in } P)^{ M} \Leftrightarrow ( A \text{ is an antichain in } P)$ whenever $M$ is a transitive ZFC model.

I recall that 'being a relation' is absolute. Is this enough to say what I want? Is being a maximal antichain also absolute for transitive models? I would think it is only downward absolute.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Being an antichain is $\Delta_0$ (& so, absolute), because all the notions that the definition uses are ($R$ is a relation on $P$, $A \subseteq P$, $(\forall x,y \in A)\, (x,y) \notin R$). Maximality is downward absolute, but upward I doubt, as in general not all subsets of $P$ will be in $M$.

Comment: @BrianO Maximality is upward absolute. $A \subseteq P$ is a maximal antichain iff (it is an antichain and) for all $p \in P$ there is some $a \in A$ such that $a$ and $p$ are compatible.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. Yes I realized later it's not a matter of subsets, just elements — either you can add another incomparable element, or you can't (& then it's maximal). Of course (in)comparability is absolute, it's just membership. I should have killed the comment, lol.

Comment: A crucial point there is *transitivity* of $M$ - if $M$ isn't transitive, then maximality isn't upwards absolute (since we may have $\mathbb{P}\cap M\not=\mathbb{P}$).